# Windows all users erased by Fedora, how to recover users for Windows login?

Tags: windows-10, login, restore

The Windows 10 directory C:\Users was deleted accidentally from a notebook's system drive (Samsung ssd 850 evo 250GB) when a user booted from a Linux Fedora 30 LiveUSB. I get an error message that says the logon user profile cannot be loaded when booting Windows. The "Users" directory appears in Fedora's Trash, but trash restoration doesn't work. How can I fix it?

I have no backup to restore.

Comment: You deleted a Windows directory while in Fedora 30, yet, within Fedora 30 you can't restore the files? You will have to recreate the users, since their profiles are gone, the data within their profile directory was deleted (and based on your description cannot be restored).

Answer (score 1):

Selectively restore from your last backup.

Comment: Unfortunately, no backup files...ㅜ.ㅜ

Comment: Why does restoration from trash fail, and what can you do about that? Otherwise, you may need to reinstall Windows, losing all user data.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Windows wouldn't need to be reinstalled.  The user's would indeed need to be created again, since the data in their profile has already been deleted, that prevents having to reinstall Windows.

Comment: thank for Ur advices.. How to create the profiles?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to repair windows 10 , that copy ￦users directory from another healthy windows 10 to c:￦ then reboot...
even thou all data file have been lost, Succeeded on booting with original user id..
Anyway I should't reinstall it thou reconfiguring all application on the windows 10.